# Django form prints no error and is not valid

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

To create a form in my website, I created some models corresponding to my fields. Then I created ModelForms from them, some views and templates. My problem is that I never see my forms errors first, and second, this particular field always has his form not valid, even with one attribute in it. Can you explain me what I'm doing wrong ?

**models.py**

```
class Grapheme(models.Model):
    lexeme = models.ForeignKey(Lexeme, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    value = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "grapheme"
        ordering = ["value"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value
```

**forms.py**

```
class GraphemeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Grapheme
        fields = ['value']
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def lexeme_edit_view(request, lexicon_id):
    [...]

    if request.method == 'POST':
        lexeme_form = LexemeForm(request.POST)
        grapheme_form = GraphemeForm(request.POST)
        [...]

        if grapheme_form.is_valid(): # This line fails
        [...]
```

**template.html**

```
{% if grapheme_form.non_field_errors %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        {% for error in grapheme_form.non_field_errors %}
            {{ error }}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endif %}

[...]

<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="graphemeInput" class="control-label col-lg-2">{{ grapheme_form.value.label }}</label>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        {% if grapheme_form.is_bound %}
            {% if grapheme_form.value.errors %}
                {% for error in grapheme_form.value.errors %}
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {{ error }}
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}

            {% if grapheme_form.value.help_text %}
                <small class="form-text text-muted">{{ grapheme_form.value.help_text }}</small>
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}

        {% render_field grapheme_form.value type="text" class+="form-control" id="graphemeInput" %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show the rest of the view. Are you passing the bound form back to the template?

Comment: Can you show us the output when u print grapheme_form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your lexeme Foreign Key on your Grapheme Model.

Since you are using django Modelforms if you do not set `blank=True`, `null=True` to a Foreign Key relationship it automatically becomes a mandatory field.

in your Form you declared that you do not want to show the lexeme foreign key selection therefore it does not appear on your form:

```
fields = ['value']
```

this is why you are getting the required field missing error on your form.

You have two possible solutions: 
**Solution 1** 
add blank=True, null=True to your foreign key relationship:

```
lexeme = models.ForeignKey(Lexeme, blank=True,null=True on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Solution 2:**
set the lexeme value when you intialize your form:

```
class GraphemeForm(Form):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    lexeme = Lexeme.objects.get(id=1)
    self.fields['lexeme'].initial = lexeme

class Meta:
    model = Grapheme
    fields = ['value']
```

Comment: No I'm not uploading anything. Here is _errors value for **Grapheme**:  <ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul>

Comment: ok I see there is a problem in how you declare the lexem foreign key and the way how you present the form in the view. I just updated my answer

Comment: All simply, I thought the form could be valid because I only assigned the _value_ to it and not the ForeignKey, but I understand now, thanks !

Comment: I also had a problem from several form fields called 'value', which resulted in an array, but that's not what I expected at first.